# SQL query to insert stats of students to a table

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql

I would like some help on how to write an sql server query in order to insert the monthly stats of students into a table.

My monthly stats table is something like this:
| StudentID | Year | Month | Grade1 | Grade2| Absences

Now I have another table with the Students Details like StudentID, name, etc. Also multiple other tables with grades, presence etc.

My goal is to select all studentsIDs from StudentDetails and insert them to the Monthly Stats table while I calculate Grade1, Grade2, and Absences from other multiple tables.

What is the best way to write such a query?

Do I first insert the StudentsIds, Year column and Month column with a select into query and after that, I iterate somehow through every studentid that were inserted and run update queries (for calculating rest of columns) for every studentID for the specified month and year?

I just need an example or some logic on how to achieve this.
For the the first part of inserting studentids I have this:

```
declare @maindate date = '20230101';

insert into Monthly_Stats (StudentID, Year, Month)
(select StudentID, AllocatedYear, AllocatedMonth
from Students_Allocation
where AllocatedMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, @maindate)
and AllocatedYear = DATEPART(YEAR, @maindate)
and Active = 1)
```

After insertion I would like somehow to update every other column (Grade1, Grade2,Absences...) from multiple other tables for each StudentID for the aforementioned Month and Year.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL for all of the tables, sample data and expected results help us help you. Why not insert the data from a `join` of all of the appropriate tables? A set-based approach is preferable to RBAR. Asides: `Grade1` and `Grade2` columns have a denormalized smell that doesn't bode well. As a rule saving a date in pieces (`AllocatedMonth` and `AllocatedYear`) is not helpful. They could be persisted computed columns if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Grade1, grade2 is just an example of a column name, they are complicated kpis that are being calculated from multiple other tables.

Comment: Every column (except studentid, month, year) like grade1, grade2, absences is being calculated from different tables. How the insert statement could be written?

Comment: `insert into Monthly_Stats ( StudentID, Year, Month, Grade1, Grade2, Absences ) select Stud.StudentInsideDiameter, MayanCalendar.Year, MayanCalendar.Month, dbo.ComplicatedKPICalculationTheFirst( HonkinListOStuff ), dbo.ComplicatedKPICalculationTheSecond( OtherHonkinListOStuff ), 0 from Students_Allocation as Stud inner join OneOfHundredsOfUnspecifiedTables as P9 on Stud.StudentID = P9.RetrenchedGammaLock left outer join TwoOfHundredsOfUnspecifiedTables as Width on Width.Shoe = P9.Heighthsic ... LunchMenu as MayanCalendar on ... where Data.Quality = 'Not just good. It''s good enough!';`

Comment: What I am asking is what logic do I use in such a situation. I am not asking you to write me a query. Let alone all these stupid stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I usually perform batch update

```
UPDATE Monthly_Stats  
SET
       Monthly_Stats.GRADE1 = T1.Somedata + T2.Somedata  + T3.Somedata  
FROM
       Monthly_Stats MS INNER JOIN TABLE_1 as T1        
left join TABLE_2 as T2 on T1.StudentID = T2.StudentID and T1.Year = T2.Year and T1.Month = T2.Month        
left join TABLE_3 as T3 on T1.StudentID = T3.StudentID and T1.Year = T3.Year and T1.Month = T3.Month 
ON 
       MS.StudentID = T1.StudentID and MS.Year = T1.Year and MS.Month = T1.Month;
```

Be careful with the two left join. Depending on your database normalization, you may need more conditions in the ON clause to ensure the join output is as expected.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I guess I will run updates after insert. Thank you.